# Doctrine using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm looking at some example documentation for Doctrine, and in the example they use SQLite. How would I get it so that it uses MySQL, with host, database, username, and password set?

In the example they use the following code:

```
// Database connection information
$connectionOptions = array(
    ‘driver’ => ‘pdo_sqlite’,
    ‘path’ => ‘database.sqlite’
);

$em – EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

Reference: http://www.slideshare.net/jwage/doctrine-2-not-the-same-old-php-orm

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Doctrine is using DBAL object as connection in EntityManager. So [that](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html) should give you an answer.